# Jakson custom serializer for list of objects

Tags: json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have a custom jackson serializer, and it works for serializing single pojos. Im trying to serialize a list of objects. Without the custom serializer I can just do:

```
public List<Sale> getAllSales() {
    return saleRepository.getAll();
}
```

which works fine, but I want to return a very specific set of data, so I made a custom serializer, which also works but only for single objects:

```
        public Sale getSale(int id) {
            
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
            module.addSerializer(Sale.class, new SaleSerializer());
            mapper.registerModule(module);
                
            Sale sale = saleRepository.findById(1).orElse(null);
    
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(sale);
        }
```

How do I do the implement the custom serializer for a list of objects?

Comment: Your `getSale()` method is not compilable.
Its declared return-type is `Sale`, but it actually returns a `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but I ended up doing it this way.

```
public ArrayNode getAllSalesToday() throws JsonProcessingException {

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay();
        LocalDateTime endOfDay = localDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Sale.class, new SaleSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        List<Sale> saleList = saleRepository.getAllByInitialDepositDateIsBetween(startOfDay,endOfDay);
        ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();

        for (Sale sale: saleList){
            String x = mapper.writeValueAsString(sale);
            JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(x);
            arrayNode.add(jsonNode);
        }

        return arrayNode;

    }
```